# Sort uppercase before lowercase in Java

Tags: java

Hello I am creating a method which sorts elements in an array alphabetically but they are sorted based on ascii. I need to sort them in a way which shows uppercase words first and then lower case words. For example if I have {Apple,Orange,Car,art,olive}, the sorting should be Apple,art,Car,Orange,olive

```
public static ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> lines) {
        lines.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
        return lines;
    }
```

This is the code I have now and I know I have to remove compareToIgnoreCase but how should I do it?

Comment: just change it for compareTo

Comment: Your example of "Apple,art,Car,Orange,olive" doesn't match your stated requirement that they need to be uppercase words and then lowercase (which is what "sorted based on ASCII" would look like).

Comment: @Stultuske it orders all uppercase letters first and then all lowercase letters.But I want uppercase A and then lowercase a and then uppercase B ect.

Comment: then indeed you'll need to write your own comparator.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Comparator.comparing()` to first compare the first letter of the word in case insensitive way and in next step use the natural order which orders uppercase before lowercase.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple","Orange","Car","art","olive");
list.sort(Comparator.<String, Character>comparing(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)))
                .thenComparing(s -> s));
System.out.println(list); // [Apple, art, Car, Orange, olive]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your own Comparator (see java.util.comparator)

You then check, if the first character is the same (using toUpperCase or toLowerCase). If it is the same, UpperCase wins. If not, you can regularly return the ordering value.

Comment: If you read the OP's question, this is not the logic they are looking for.